# Why might lab test results be normal when thyroid nodules are present and there are symptoms of hyperthyroidism?

Tags: thyroid, hyperthyroid

By ultrasound there are many nodules in Thyroid gland but all thyroid tests (TSH,T4,T3, microsomal and thyreoglobulin antibodies) are within normal range but there is clear heperthyroidism signs like hair thinning,anxiety,irritability,cardio neurosis,fatigue etc. Why lab tests don't show any disfunction? What is the cause of these overactive thyroid signs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This constellation may result from at least five reasons:

1. Hypothesis #0: Both conditions (thyroid nodules and symptoms of
   hyperthyroidism) are independent. Hyperthyroid symptoms including
   anxiety, hair loss, fatigue and palpitations are unspecific.
   Although they are typical for thyrotoxicosis, they may also result
   from other conditions, e.g. masked depression or pheochromocytoma.
2. Hypothesis #1: The nodules represent fully compensated toxic
   adenomas, where somatic mutations lead to constitutive activation of
   TSH signaling. Since autonomic production is fully compensated,
   concentrations of thyroid hormones remain within their respective
   reference ranges. Symptoms of thyrotoxicosis result from deviation
   of free T4 concentrations from the personal set point of thyroid
   homeostasis. It is well known that the intra-individual variation of
   TSH and free T4 concentrations is much smaller than inter-individual
   variance (see http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11889165 and
   http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25567792 ). This is a consequence
   of an individual set point of the pituitary-thyroid feedback control
   mechanism, which is encoded as TRH signaling from the hypothalamus.
   Deviations of thyroid hormones within the reference range may still
   lead to symptoms if they are far from the personal set point. See
   http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26635726 for a review article
   discussing this topic and
   http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24480737 for a method for
   reconstructing the personal set point.
3. Hypothesis #2: This is somewhat similar to hypotheses #1. The
   nodules represent fully compensated toxic adenomas (like in
   hypothesis #1), but they predominantly produce T3, which results
   from intracellular hyperdeiodination (ensuing from constitutive
   activation of TSH signaling and consecutive stimulation of the
   distal part of the TSH-T3 shunt). T3 concentrations remain within
   their reference ranges, but are above the range of concentrations
   that are appropriate for the personal receptor sensitivity. See
   http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23339744/ for a discussion of
   this topic. It may be helpful to calculate the sum activity of
   peripheral deiodinases (SPINA-GD), see also
   http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27375554 for a methodological
   overview.
4. Hypothesis #3: The thyroid nodules produce non-classical thyroid
   hormones (e.g. 3,5-T2, a highly active T4 metabolite), which
   destabilize the heart rhythm and exert other symptoms of
   hyperthyroidism. This is an understudied topic. One of the few
   papers discussing this condition is
   http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26279999 .
5. Hypothesis #4: T3 is secreted episodically from thyroid nodules, so
   that it is missed from diagnostic work-up. This is also an
   understudied topic. See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2045066
   for more details.

It may be beneficial to determine concentrations of free T3 and free T4 (rather than total T3 and total T4) in order to avoid false negative results due to low plasma protein binding.